# How can I encrypt a file with gpg non-interactively?

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I want to write a script that automatically encrypts a file using gpg and a password that is saved in a file.

I tried this:

```
gpg -c --passphrase-fd 0 file.txt < pass.txt
```

When I run this on an Ubuntu 16.04 server, it encrypts the file, as expected.
When I run it on an Ubuntu 18.04 desktop, it asks me for a passphrase, using the Password Manager modal dialog.

How can I skip the dialog and do a non-interactive encryption?

As a workaround, I did this using openssl instead of gpg:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -pass file:pass.txt -e -in file.txt -out file.txt.enc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested in my Lubuntu 18.04 LTS.

- Your command line fails for me in the same way as you describe.
- **The following command line works for me**,

  ```
  gpg --batch -c --passphrase-file pass.txt file.txt
  ```

See details in `man gpg`

> ```
>    --passphrase-file file
>           Read  the passphrase from file file. Only the first line will be
>           read from  file  file.  This  can  only  be  used  if  only  one
>           passphrase is supplied. Obviously, a passphrase stored in a file
>           is of questionable security if other users can read  this  file.
>           Don't  use  this  option  if  you  can avoid it.  Note that this
>           passphrase is only used if the  option  --batch  has  also  been
>           given.  This is different from GnuPG version 1.x.
> ```

Comment: So the trick is to use --batch.  Then both --passphrase-file and --passphrase-fd work.  --passphrase-file was my first choice.

Comment: @user13097, I'm glad I could help you make it work :-)

Answer (score 2):

Or if you don't want to create a passphrase file, like when you are writing a script, You can use it like this:

> `gpg --batch --passphrase 'somepass' -c file.txt`